# Knowing which pixel or UV you are on with GLSL?

Tags: glsl

Right now I can obtain the color of the neighbouring pixel  by doing

```
color = texture2D(backBuffer, vec2(gl_TexCoord[0].x + i,gl_TexCoord[0].y + j);
```

But how can I know what pixel that is or at least the current uv of that pixel on the texture?

Which pixel of the fragment. The UV / ST is a number from 0 to 1 representing the whole texture.

I want to calculate a pixels brightness based on its distance from a point.

Comment: Which pixel from the pixel shader? What is UV of a pixel??

Comment: @VJo Which pixel of the fragment. The UV / ST is a number from 0 to 1 representing the whole texture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gl_TexCoord[0].x` gives you the s texture coordinate, while `gl_TexCoord[0].y` gives you the s texture coordinate.

If you are writing fragment shader, the pixel position shouldn't matter. I haven't tried, but maybe you can get it using `gl_in`, which is defined as :

```
in gl_PerVertex {
vec4 gl_Position;
float gl_PointSize;
float gl_ClipDistance[];
} gl_in[];
```

but I am not sure it if it available for pixel shader.